# Is it bad practice to use Inheritance to associate methods with a basic container?

Tags: c++

Basically, I have code that looks like this.  It's a `typedef` and a set of methods that revolve around that `typedef`.

```
class foo {
    // Foo stuff...

    // Registration Stuff
    private:
        typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> MTRegistrationParams;

        void DispatchRegistrationMessage (MTRegistrationParams const &, std::string destination_id);
        static std::string BuildRegistrationMessage (MTRegistrationParams const &, std::string message_id); // Only called by DispatchRegistrationMessage

    // more Foo stuff...
};
```

I am thinking it might be clearer to just make a little mini-class, to help logically separate those methods from Foo's structure.

```
class foo {
    // Foo stuff...

    // Registration Stuff
    private:
        struct MTRegistrationParams : public std::map<std::string, std::string> {
            void DispatchRegistrationmessage (foo &, std::string const & destination_id);
            private:
                std::string BuildRegistrationMessage (std::string const & message_id);
    };

    // more Foo stuff...
};
```

The thing is... I don't usually make derived classes unless for the sake of inheriting methods, and deriving from a standard container seems REALLY weird.

Am I being overly concerned, or is deriving from standard containers just to decorate them with methods genuinely bad practice?

Comment: I don't see any problems with the first approach. It is pretty clear and simple. Don't overcomplicate things for nothing.

Comment: @glampert, I don't think it's for nothing. When you have functions in a class that deal exclusively (or close) with methods/state/data of another class, that's a clear indication to refactor (i.e. `DispatchRegistrationMessage` and `BuildRegistrationMessage` receive a map as a parameter, because that's what they operate on; they should _probably_ be in the map class - in this case, "the map class" means the extracted/refactored `MTRegistrationParams`)

Answer (score 3):

Deriving from a C++ standard container **should** look really weird, because they were never designed to be used as a base class.

The biggest source of problems is if your 'extended' container needs to override behavior of the underlying container (including the destructor!), or if your 'extended' container has additional constraints that don't exist for the underlying standard container.
When passing such an 'extended' container as a pointer/reference to a function that expects a standard container, that function can inadvertently break the invariants of the 'extended' container by calling the wrong functions of the base class. And if you happen to destruct an 'extended' container through a pointer to its base class, you land yourself in undefined behavior.

In the example of this question, the chances for such incorrect behavior are next to nil, but if you start using this pattern, it is easy to land in situations where it *does* matter. For that reason, it is strongly recommended **not** to derive from the standard containers.

Also, the `DispatchRegistrationMessage` method isn't that much easier to use, because now you need to pass in a `Foo` object and it is very inconvenient to use overloaded operators (like `operator[]` of `std::map`) on `this`.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I being overly concerned, or is deriving from standard containers just to decorate them with methods genuinely bad practice?

No, you are right to be concerned. The `std` containers were not meant to be inherited, only encapsulated (and inheriting from them should be UB).

I think your final solution should be along these lines:

```
class MTRegistrationParams {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> data; // encapsulated
public:
    void DispatchRegistrationmessage (std::string const & destination_id);

    decltype(data.begin()) begin() { return data.begin(); }
    decltype(data.end()) end() { return data.end(); }
    decltype(data.size()) size() { return data.size(); }
    // forward ano other map methods you need, here
private:
    std::string BuildRegistrationMessage (std::string const & message_id);
};

class foo {
    // Foo stuff...

    // Registration Stuff
private:
    typedef MTRegistrationParams params;

    // more Foo stuff...
};
```

Comment: Any reference (e.g. to some precise part of the C+11 standard) about inheriting from standard containers is undefined behavior. I know it is bad practice, but why UB?

Comment: My kingdom for “delegation” to be added to C++ for just these situations.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, since the map destructor is not virtual, it will not be called, unless you call it explicitly. This means that any objects inside the map will not get destroyed, and that can mean anything from a memory leak, to a deadlock in the application (depending on what those destructors needed to do).

Comment: @utnapistim, it would be UB only if you were to attempt to `delete` an instance of the type inherited from map. If you only have statically allocated objects, it is fine. The map destructor still gets called. E.g.: This: `MTRegistrationParams p;` is OK. `MTRegistrationParams * p = new MTRegistrationParams();` is UB when you try to delete it.

Comment: @glampert nope, the latter is not UB, since the static type of the pointer is the right one, so `~MTRegistrationParams` is called. However, this would lead to UB: `std::map<std::string, std::string>* pMap = new MTRegistrationParams(); delete pMap;`

Comment: Standard reference for my comment: C++11, [expr.delete], §5.3.5,3: "[...] **if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type**, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined." (emphasis mine)

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense :), Thanks @ArneMertz

Comment: To sum up the previous comments: as the destructor isn't virtual, while inheriting is technically fine yet calling `delete` on a pointer to the base class is UB. Nothing special about `std` container, though.

Answer (score -1):

it is fine. Because foo class is not associated logicaly with MTRegistrationParams. its is better to provide inner class. So if user want to use foo only then no need to expose MTRegistrationParams' functionalities. like iterator for list.

Comment: You missed the point of the question. It is fine to create inner class but it is **not** fine to derive it from `std::map`.

Comment: @ Jan Hudec  : why is there a problem to derive inner class from std::map. is it because of template ? please explain me to improve my knowledge

Comment: Collections don't have any virtual methods, so you don't get anything and you risk breaking the subclass invariants by direct calls to the base class methods. It's better to delegate.